# How to create a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to calculate data on the frequencies of words in documents grouped by year, and then place the data in a pandas dataframe.

My routine creates a dictionary for each row, containing words and frequencies as keys and values. I then want to loop through years, appending the dictionaries to each other to create a list of dictionaries which i convert into a dataframe.

Creating dataframes out of lists of dictionaries seems standard; and i can do it by manually creating the list.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
wordtable = {'year':'1965','word1':20, 'word2': 250, 'word3': 125}
newrow={'year':'1966','word1':150, 'word4': 250, 'word2': 125}
wordtable.append(newrow)

df = pandas.DataFrame(wordtable, index=[0])
df.to_csv('testdata.csv')
```

But .append() leads to an error message stating .append() doesn't work with dictionary types.

Comment: Try `wordtable = [{'year':'1965','word1':20, 'word2': 250, 'word3': 125}]`. `append()` is a `list` method.

Comment: thanks! but if i convert my dictionaries into lists with list(), the dataframe command doesn't seem to work. i'm puzzled by the fact lots of panda documentation discusses 'lists of dictionaries'.

Comment: You don't want multiple lists of dictionaries, you want *a list* of dictionaries. See piRSquared's answer.

Comment: @Jon Don't convert with `list`. You want a nested structure, i.e. a list that contains dictionaries. So `[{...}, {...}]` is what it will look like, the `...` being your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wordtable` needs to be a list of dictionaries.  Then use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`

```
wordtable = [{'year':'1965','word1':20, 'word2': 250, 'word3': 125}]
newrow={'year':'1966','word1':150, 'word4': 250, 'word2': 125}
wordtable.append(newrow)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(wordtable)
df
```

[image]

Comment: @Jon if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the chosen answer.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster mentioned, append() is a list method but not a dict method. This should work, though:

```
import pandas

word_data = []  # list type
word_counts_1 = {'year': '1965', 'word1':20, 'word2': 250, 'word3': 125}  # dict type
word_counts_2 = {'year':'1966','word1':150, 'word4': 250, 'word2': 125}  # dict type
word_data.append(word_counts_1)  # append 1st word count data to list, word_data
word_data.append(word_counts_2)  # append 2nd word count data to list, word_data
df = pandas.DataFrame(word_data)  # create data frame from word_data
df.to_csv('testdata.csv')  # write it out
```